# Can someone explain the source of the `cd` shell command?

Tags: freebsd

```
$ cat $(which cd)
#!/bin/sh
# $FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/alias/generic.sh,v 1.2 2005/10/24 22:32:19   cperciva Exp $
# This file is in the public domain.
builtin `echo ${0##*/} | tr \[:upper:] \[:lower:]` ${1+"$@"}
```

My interest lies in understanding who records the state change after calling cd. Is it in a file?

Comment: That's not the source of the `cd` builtin; that's the source of a shell script that calls the builtin.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you looking for source code? It's a shell builtin. The shell keeps up with what directory it considers the working directory.

Comment: The builtin has no source; it's built into the shell (as the name says).

Comment: Related: [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **not** the `cd` builtin, and it doesn't actually work, except to tell if a directory *can* be changed into, by failing with a nonzero exit status if it cannot.

Try it:

```
"$(which cd)" /
```

...will do nothing.

---

The actual `cd` builtin is part of your shell, written in C, and calls the `chdir()` syscall. This syscall updates your process's state -- tracked by the kernel -- to have a different working directory.

---

...so, what *is* that chunk of shell script doing? Let's break it down:

```
builtin `echo ${0##*/} | tr \[:upper:] \[:lower:]` ${1+"$@"}
```

...first, we're `echo`ing the command itself (in a somewhat buggy fashion, due to the lack of quotes) into `tr`, and changing it to all lower-case, such that if it were being called via a hardlink named `CD` it would still map to the builtin named `cd`.

...second, `${1+"$@"}` is passing all arguments (`"$@"`) through, **if** there are any arguments (`${foo+bar}` expands to `bar` only if `foo` is defined).

Thus, we're calling the shell-builtin `cd` (which in turn calls the `chdir()` syscall), with arguments passed through. The reason this builtin has no effect other than determining success or failure is because it's running out-of-process from the executable that invoked it -- so it changes the working directory of the shell started by the `#!/bin/sh` shebang, but not of any process or shell above that in the tree.

---

So, what does a **real** `cd` builtin look like? Since it's short and easy-to-read, let's look at the Busybox `ash` implementation.

- [Here](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/busybox/blob/7dc8052a09ea684200e86e0c340be80854521bdf/shell/ash.c#L2632) is the entry-point...
- [Here](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/busybox/blob/7dc8052a09ea684200e86e0c340be80854521bdf/shell/ash.c#L2604) is the actual operation.
- [Here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) is the manual for the syscall invoked by the actual operation.