# What is the `Cd` command?

Tags: bash, macos, freebsd

I was writing some code, navigating my computer (OSX 10.11.6) via the command line, like I always do, and I made a typo! Instead of typing:

```
cd USB
```

I typed

```
Cd USB
```

Nothing happened, but it didn't register as an invalid command. Perplexed by this, I did some investigating: I checked the `man` entry. There was no entry. I found the source file (`/usr/bin/Cd`) using `which Cd`, and then `cat`ed it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/alias/generic.sh,v 1.2 2005/10/24 22:32:19 cperciva Exp $
# This file is in the public domain.
builtin `echo ${0##*/} | tr \[:upper:] \[:lower:]` ${1+"$@"}
```

What is this, and why is it here? How does it relate to freeBSD?

Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Comment: This question is better suited on [unix/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Looking at the code I would say it converts Cd to cd and executes as expected a cd USB :-) ..?

Comment: @cat That's what the general consensus seems to be. Somewhat annoying stacks of different technologies on top of each other produce a strange result. Bash is case-sensitive, OSX isn't, this leads to some confusion, and me just being stupid ;)

Comment: OSX *may* be case-insensitive, it depends on how the disk was formatted, e.g., http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22304

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776286/can-someone-explain-the-source-of-the-cd-shell-command

Comment: Funny, I answered this question in a different guise within the last few days. (This is actually the better asking, perhaps).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**macOS uses a *case-insensitive* filesystem by default**<sup>[1]</sup>
, which can be misleading at times:

**`which Cd` is effectively the same as `which cd` and `which CD`** in terms of returning the (effectively) same file path.

Confusingly, even though all 3 command refer to the *same* file, they do so in a *case-preserving* manner, misleadingly suggesting that the actual case of the filename is *whatever you specified*.

As a workaround, you can see the true case of the filename if you employ *globbing* (filename expansion):

```
$ ls "$(which Cd)"*  # could match additional files, but the one of interest is among them
/usr/bin/cd  # true case of the filename
```

---

**Bash (the macOS default shell) is internally *case-sensitive***.
That is, **it recognizes `cd` as builtin `cd`** (its built-in directory-changing command).

By contrast, **it does NOT recognize `Cd` as that**, due to the difference in case.

Given that it doesn't recognize `Cd` as a builtin, it **goes looking for an *external utility* (in the `$PATH`), and that is when it finds `/usr/bin/cd`**.

---

**`/usr/bin/cd` is implemented as a *shell script***, which is **mostly useless**, because as an external utility it cannot affect the shell's state, so its attempts to change the directory are simply quietly ignored.
([Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) points out in a comment that you can use it as *test* whether a given directory can be changed to, because the script's exit code will reflect that).

[Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810141/45375) provides history behind the inclusion of the script in FreeBSD and OSX (which mostly builds on FreeBSD), but it's worth **taking a closer look at the rationale** (emphasis mine):

From the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06):

> However, **all of the standard utilities, including the regular built-ins** in the table, but not the special built-ins described in Special Built-In Utilities, **shall be implemented in a manner so that they can be accessed via the exec family of functions** as defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008 and can be invoked directly by those standard utilities that require it (env, find, nice, nohup, time, xargs).

In essence, the above means: **regular built-ins must (also) be callable *stand-alone*, as *executables*** (whether as scripts or binaries), nut just as built-ins from within the shell.

The cited **regular built-ins** table comprises these utilities:

`alias bg cd command false fc fg getopts jobs kill newgrp pwd read true umask unalias wait`

<sup>Note: *special* built-in utilities are by definition shell-internal only, and their behavior differs from regular built-in utilities.</sup>

As such, **to be *formally* POSIX-compliant an OS must indeed provide `cd` as an *external utility***.

At the same time, the POSIX spec. does have awareness that at least *some* of these regular built-ins - notably `cd` - only makes sense *as a built-in*:

"Since `cd` affects the current shell execution environment, it is **always provided as a shell regular built-in.**" - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html

Among the regular built-in utilities listed, ***some* make sense *both* as a built-in *and* as an external utility**:

For instance `kill` needs to be a *built-in* in order to kill *jobs* (which are a shell-*internal* concept), but it is also useful as an *external utility*, so as to kill processes by PID.

**However, among the regular built-in utilities listed, the following *never* make sense as *external* utilities, as far as I can tell <sup>Do tell me if you disagree</sup>
, even though POSIX mandates their presence**:

`alias bg cd command fc fg getopts jobs read umask unalias`

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318694/matt) for helping to complete the list; he also points that the `hash` built-in, even though it's not a POSIX utility, also has a pointless script implementation.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] As [Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) points out in a comment, it is *possible* to format HFS+, the macOS filesystem, in a case-*sensitive* manner (even though most people stick with the case-insensitive default). Based on [the answer Dave links to](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22304), the following command will tell you whether your macOS filesystem is case-insensitive or not:

`diskutil info / | grep -iq '^\s*Name.*case-sensitive*' && echo "case-SENSITIVE" || echo "case-INsensitive"`</sup>

Comment: @Droppy: Yes, `cd` is a built-in command. But some systems, including apparently MacOS provide an external `/usr/bin/cd` command as well. The external command is far less useful than the built-in `cd` command. See my answers for more information.

Comment: OSX case sensitivity depends on formatting, e.g., http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22304

Comment: The external command lets you test whether it's possible to change to a directory without actually doing so. (I've never encountered a use for it, particularly since I mostly use systems that don't have `/usr/bin/cd`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: While you _can_ use the script `/usr/bin/cd` that way, all indications are that the rationale for providing the script wasn't any _practical_ purpose, but _POSIX compliance_ - see my updated answer.

Comment: simple question, epic answer. This is unix/posix/bsd in a nutshell  : )

Answer (score 3):

### What is this?

The script itself is a portable way to convert a command, even with random upper casing, into the equivalent shell `builtin` based on the exec paths file name, that is any part of the string after the final `/` in the `$0` variable). The script then runs the builtin command with the same arguments.

As OSX file systems are case insensitive by default, `/usr/bin/cd` converts running `Cd`, `CD`, `cD` and any form of `cd` with a `/` fs path (like `/usr/bin/cd`) back to the shell builtin command `cd`. This is largely useless in  a script as `cd` only affects the current shell it is running in, which immediately closes when the script ends.

### How does it relate to freeBSD?

A similar [file exists in FreeBSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/af3e10e5a78d3af8cef6088748978c6c612757f0/usr.bin/alias/generic.sh), which Apple adapted to do case conversion. Mac file systems by default are case insensitive (but case preserving).

The `$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/alias/generic.sh,v 1.2 2005/10/24 22:32:19 cperciva Exp $` header is the source information in the file.

Most of the underlying OSX system comes directly from FreeBSD or was based on it. The Windowing system on top of this and the Cocoa app layer is where OSX becomes truly Apple. Some of the lower level Apple bits have even made it back into FreeBSD like [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) and [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) compiler.

### Why is it here?

The [earlier FreeBSD svn commits](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=100200) shed a bit of light:

> A little bit more thought has resulted in a generic script which can
>   implement any of the useless POSIX-required ``regular shell builtin''
>   utilities...

Although most builtins aren't very useful when run in a new shell via a script, this compliance script was used for the commands `alias bg cd command fc fg getopts hash jobs read type ulimit umask unalias wait`. [POSIX compliance is fun!](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06)

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, MacOS uses a case-insensitive file system by default. The command you saw as `/usr/bin/Cd` is actually `/usr/bin/cd`, but it can be referred to by either name.

You can see this by typing

```
ls /usr/bin/ | grep -i cd
```

Normally `cd` is a builtin command in the shell. As you know, it changes the current directory. An external `cd` command is nearly useless -- but it still exists.

It can be used to detect whether it's possible to change to a specified directory without actually affecting the working directory of your current process.

Your shell (probably bash) tends to assume case-sensitive command names. The builtin command can only be referred to as `cd`, but since it's able to open the script file named `/usr/bin/Cd`, it can find and execute it.